# How do I embed a hyper link text into the p tag text?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Scrapy and having trouble when dealing with hyper links. The article will have a name but that would be a hyperlink to another page. I can't figure out how to embed the  tag text with the

tag text. I am trying to practice [on this article](http://www.espn.com/nba/story/_/id/20144300/zach-lowe-kyrie-irving-cleveland-cavaliers-potential-trades-nba).

`response.css('div.article-body p::text').extract()`

Comment: could you form a more clear question? what exactly are you trying to do? embed a hyperlink text in p text? please try to re-word or be more specific about what the expected result is.

Comment: @eusid if you look at the link I provided you will see hyper links when I extract the main content they are not included since they are a tags and not apart of the p tag text.

Comment: pretty sure my answer below is what you are looking for to extract full text

Comment: so were u able to solve the problem with my solution if so please accept answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a css wild card selector.

```
response.css('div.article-body p *::text').extract()
```

Alternatively, if you wanted everything inside div.article-body

```
response.css('div.article-body *::text').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier way would be to use the XPath functions `string()` or `normalize-space()` like:

```
response.css('.article-body > p').xpath('normalize-space(.)').extract()
```